# Joint distribution of continuous and discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $Y$ be a continuous random variable with PDF:
$$f_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}
3 y^{2} &, & 0<y<1 \\
0 &,& \textrm { else }
\end{cases}$$

Also $X$ is a discrete random variable such that:
$$P\left(X=x \mid Y=y\right)~=~y(1-y)^{x-1}\:,x \in \mathbb{N}$$

Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

I am confused in this question.

As I know:
$$P\left(X=x \mid Y=y\right)~=~\frac{P\left(X=x, Y=y\right)}{P(Y=y)}$$
But how to find $P(Y=y)$?

Comment: $P(Y=y)=0$, for all $y\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is neither jointly discrete nor jointly continuous, but rather a mixed one. To properly describe such distribution, you will need a new type of "density".

Before getting to the problem, let me give a brief review of PMF (probability mass function) and PDF (probability density function).

- Suppose there exists a non-negative function $p(x)$ that satisfies the following property:
  $$ \mathbf{P}(X \in A) = \sum_{x \in A} p(x) $$
  for any "reasonable" subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$. We remind that such $p$ need not always exists. If this is the case, however, then $X$ is called **discrete**, and such $p$ is called the **PMF** of $X$.
- Suppose there exists a non-negative function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following property:
  $$ \mathbf{P}(X \in A) = \int_A f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$
  for any "reasonable" subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Again, such $f$ need not always exists. If it does, however, then $X$ is called **continuous**, and such $f$ is called the **PDF** of $X$.
- Joint PMFs and joint PDFs of two RVs $X$ and $Y$ are defined likewise, adapting the above definitions. For example, $(X, Y)$ is said to be jointly continuous if there exists a non-negative function $f(x, y)$ such that
  $$ \mathbf{P}((X, Y) \in A) = \int_{A} f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}x $$
  for any "reasonable" subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If this is the case, then $f$ is called the joint PDF of $X$.

Now let us come back to your question. In your setting, $Y$ is continuous and $X$ is discrete with a specified conditional distribution given $Y$. So, using the law of total probability, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(X \in A, Y \in B)
&= \int_B \mathbf{P}(X \in A \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_B \left( \sum_{x \in A} \mathbf{P}(X =x \mid Y = y) \right) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \sum_{x \in A} \int_B \mathbf{P}(X =x \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

So, the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ can be described by the function $q_{X,Y}$ below, which is kind of an intermediate of PMF and PDF:

\begin{align*}
q_{X,Y}(x, y)
&= \mathbf{P}(X = x \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) \\[0.25em]
&= \begin{cases}
3y^3(1-y)^{x-1}, & x \in \mathbb{N}, \ 0 < y < 1, \\
0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

and the probabilities for $(X, Y)$ can be recovered by the formula

$$ \mathbf{P}((X, Y) \in A \times B) = \sum_{x \in A} \int_B q_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

---

<sub>*Addendum.* I am not sure if there is a commonly used term for something like $q_{X,Y}$. However, if you have a chance to revisit probability theory in measure-theoretic viewpoint in a future, you will recognize both PMFs and PDFs as the Radon–Nikodym derivatives with respective to the counting measure and Lebesgue measure, respectively. This way, the theory of PMF/PDF can be unified into a single, general setting. Then $q_{X,Y}$ in this problem is nothing but the Radon–Nikodym derivative of the distribution of $(X, Y)$ with respect to the product of the counting and Lebesgue measure.</sub>