Expectation of discrete-continuous joint random variable
Say I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $Y$ is continuous and $X$ is discrete. Based on the definitions of independence for two continuous random variables and for two discrete random variables, I believe their joint distribution is $$f(x,y)=p_X(x)f_Y(y)$$ where $p_X$ is the probability mass function of $X$ and $f_Y$ is the probability density function of $Y$. I also think it is possible that $$E[g(X,Y)]=\sum_x\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x,y)f(x,y)\:dy$$ where $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.
Are these relations correct? Could someone explain how they are derived or provide a source that does so? I've looked through a few introductory probability textbooks but haven't been able to find an explicit mention of these results.

There is a good answer about the joint distribution in this scenario: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463435/1008276
